# ArcMap Spatial Join Tool Equivalent In Hadoop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hadoop

Does anyone know the equivalent of the [spatial join](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) tool in ArcMap that can be used in Hadoop?

I am trying to join point and polygon data in Hadoop and create a new point files that adds the attributes of the polygon data.

Comment: Edit the title to "in Hadoop" rather than "in ArcMap"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapt the [GIS Tools for Hadoop samples of Point-in-Polygon join](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/tree/master/samples), to output the desired info, rather than output counts.

Something to the effect of the following *untested* query:

`SELECT earthquakes.*, counties.* from earthquakes, counties
WHERE ST_Contains(counties.boundaryshape, ST_Point(earthquakes.longitude, earthquakes.latitude));`

[disclosure: collaborator]

Comment: I was able to use: SELECT eventid
FROM earthquakes
JOIN counties
WHERE counties.name = 'San Bernardino'
AND ST_Contains(counties.boundaryshape, ST_Point(earthquakes.longitude, earthquakes.latitude));  This gives me the earthquakes located within an individual county but i wanted to get a list of earthquakes for each county.

Comment: Might be possible with Hive ARRAY - you could try looking up samples or reference documentation, and/or ask a separate question, about using ARRAY in HQL/SQL.

Comment: SELECT counties.name, earthquakes.eventid
FROM counties
JOIN earthquakes 
WHERE ST_Contains(counties.boundaryshape, ST_Point(earthquakes.longitude, earthquakes.latitude))
GROUP BY name, eventid                                              This code let me list the polygon each point was in.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be spatial aggregation based on this article.

https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/03/25/new-spatial-aggregation-tutorial-for-gis-tools-for-hadoop/

Comment: That article on spatial binning, plus the [GIS Tools for Hadoop samples of Point-in-Polygon join](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/tree/master/samples), should provide the info needed to develop a spatial join.  [collaborator]

Comment: Geoffrey this would give me the count of points in a polygon. What i was looking for was returning the polygon each point is located within.